# Getting error while trying to automate web login using selenium web driver in python 3.6

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

Below is my code and getting this error only some times. Surprisingly, when i run the same code line by line, it is working as expected!

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.gmail.com')
email=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
email.send_keys('my email-id')
next=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span')
next.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(9)
passwd=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
passwd.send_keys('mypassword')
next1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span')
next1.click()
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <span class="RveJvd snByac">...</span> is not clickable at point (942, 426). Other element would receive the click: <div class="
ANuIbb IdAqtf" jsname="k4HEge" tabindex="0"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Can you please show your html code? //*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input this xpath not found

Comment: @zsbappa: HTML code for password:                                                                            <input type="password" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">

Answer (score 0):

Hope Your Problem will be solved

```
        from selenium import webdriver
        browser=webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.maximize_window()
        browser.get('https://www.gmail.com')
        email=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
        email.send_keys('my email-id')
        next=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span')
        next.click()
        passwd=browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        passwd.send_keys('mypassword')
        next1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span')
        next1.click()
```

Comment: it is stuck at password prompt.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 9, in <module>
    passwd=browser.driver.find_element_by_name('password')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"password"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Please check this documentation for python location element.It not a problem on program it a problem on your XPath locators
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work out for you. The basic idea is to wait for the password field until its ready in DOM

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.gmail.com')
email=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
email.send_keys('my email-id')
next=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span')
next.click()
passwd=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(passwd))
passwd.send_keys('mypassword')
next1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span')
next1.click()
```

Comment: File "web.py", line 10
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i resolved the error by adding an implicit wait.                                                           browser.implicitly_wait(9)